# can't insert data in a mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

first of all i am pretty new with mysql and php and for now i just want to insert some data in a mysql database form two text box using php.

here the database name is "info" and table name is "students" having three columns like id(primary key, auto increment activated), name and dept. There are two text boxes txtName and txtDept. I want that when i press the enter button the data form the text boxes will be inserted into the mysql database. I have tried the following code but data is not being inserted in the table....

```
<html>

<form mehtod="post" action="home.php">
    <input type="text" name="txtName" />
    <input type="text" name="txtDept" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>

</form>
</html> 

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","info");
if($_POST){

    $name = $_POST['txtName'];
    $dept = $_POST['txtDept'];
    echo $name;
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO students(name,dept) VALUES($name,$dept);");


}

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your *posted* code.

`mehtod="post"` it should be `method="post"` - typo.

Plus, quote your VALUES

`VALUES('$name','$dept')`

DO use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

because your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

and add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You should also check for DB errors.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","info")   
          or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
```

as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

---

***Sidenote/suggestion:***

If your entire code is inside the same file (*which appears to be*), consider wrapping your PHP/SQL inside a conditional statement using the submit button named attribute, otherwise, you may get an `Undefined index...` warning.

Naming your submit button `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"/>`

and doing

`if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ code to execute }`

Just doing `if($_POST){` may give unexpected results when error reporting is set.

---

***Rewrite:*** with some added security using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)

```
<html>

<form method="post" action="home.php">
    <input type="text" name="txtName" />
    <input type="text" name="txtDept" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"/>

</form>
</html> 

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","info")  
         or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name = stripslashes($_POST['txtName']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['txtName']);

    $dept = stripslashes($_POST['txtDept']);
    $dept = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['txtDept']);
    echo $name;

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `students` (`name`, `dept`) VALUES ('$name','$dept')")   
           or die(mysqli_error($con));

}

?>
```

---

As per the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php and if you wish to use the following method where a comment has been given to that effect:

```
<?php
$link = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: @VMai I don't understand. Edit, ok got it.

Comment: @VMai Good point. Made the edit, yet the `VALUES...` at the end, kind of looks strange when I was going to put it under `mysqli_query`. Feel free to edit :)

Comment: To check for connection errors in this case you may use `mysqli_connect_error()`, because in case of error `$con` will be `FALSE` and `mysqli_error()` needs valid link identifier.

Comment: It can't work out every time. I try to avoid it if I can. Idea: Rewrite it as a prepared statement with prepare, bind, execute and the line shouldn't be too long anymore.

Comment: @VMai Indeed, the lines won't be as long and be much safer. The OP has been given the link to using prepared statements. ;)

Comment: @Timur Good point, thank you. I have made an edit to that effect.

Comment: As usual, a very depth answer. No need to keep mine around. +1

Answer (score 0):

God save us all... 
Use PDO class instead :). By using PDO you can additionally make prepared statement on client side and use named parameters. More over if you ever have to change your database driver PDO support around 12 different drivers (eighteen different databases!) where MySQLi supports only one driver (MySQL). :(
In term of performance MySQLi is around 2,5% faster however this is not a big difference at all. My choice is PDO anyway :).